# PyQt и Qt Creator

Tags: python, qt, qtcreator, pyqt5

Добрый день,

пытаюсь разбираться с Qt, а именно с PyQt и как-то совсем прогресса нет. Не могли бы вы мне объяснить следующие вещи:

- что использовать как IDE? В интернете пишут, мол Qt Designer нужен, который нужно использовать через Qt Creator и тут вообще ступор, так как нигде не нахожу первого. Что вообще представляет из себя Qt Designer?
- допустим я уже пишу код в какой-то из сред, будет возможность писать на python-e и потом запускать это? Или всё сводится к тому, что мучу .ui файлы и через консоль запускаю?
- если под Ubuntu работаю, то как всё это мракобессие запустить? В pip поставил PyQt, вроде как должен был быть Qt Designer (по крайней мере мне так обещали), его нет. Попытался поставить пакет PyQt-tools, pip кричит, что не может поставить.

В итоге в голове каша, ничего не понимаю. Может кто-нибудь из вас поможет эту кашу разгрести?

Comment: старайтесь в одном вопросе, одной проблемой ограничиваться. Если не знаете где начать, начните с вводных руководств. Появится конкретная проблема, спрашивайте.

Comment: @jfs просто всего столько скопилось, что мозг взрывает. Но воспользуюсь случаем и спрошу вас : что из себя представляет Qt Designer?

Comment: @koshachok, designer — это WYSIWYG редактор интерфейса (*.ui-файлов), т.е. рисовалка окошечек. Евляется частью Qt. Очень полезен, если нет желания создавать весь UI из кода. И он и PyQt есть в стандартных репах всех [в разумных пределах] дистрибутивов.

Comment: да можно вообще не трогать не qtcreator не qtdisigner, через пип ставите библиотеки и запускаетесь как обычный python-файл, IDE при этом можете использовать к какой привыкли, в ubuntu запускать из терминала :)

Comment: @StefanBloodhawk , я не очень понял? Ну вообще я ручками начал клепать интерфейс, что не очень приятно. Так вы рекомендуете использовать какой либо редактор для .ui? Как IDE использую PyCharm.

Comment: руками "клепать" интерфейс полезно :) если у вас не слишком сложный интерфейс - можно вполне обойтись и без .ui, руками в pycharm. есть ide, вроде как, заточенные под pyqt (eric, wing), но лично меня их стабильность не устроила. ну, если совсем уж не охота руками интерфейс набирать, то вот qtdesigner+любая IDE  http://pythonforengineers.com/your-first-gui-app-with-python-and-pyqt/

Answer (score 1):

О, мой друг, вижу тебе не хватает страданий в жизни? Вообще, сборка `PyQt5` из исходников представляет собой 2-3 дня боли только на `Windows` OS. Есть много гайдов по сборке последней версии `PyQt5` на `*nix` системах. Единственное, помню, что когда последний раз пытался вытянуть исходники `PyQt5`, `sourceforge` был в шатдауне, в следствии чего, в сентябре прошлого года я начал изучать `C++` и в итоге полностью першел на чистый `Qt`. Я помню, что необходимо было иметь установленный `Qt` соответствующей версии в системе и при сборке `Python`овской привязки указывать пути к `C++` версии. Кстати, разработчики `Qt` недавно объявили, что выпустят свою, официальную версию привязки `Qt` к `Python`, с преферансом и техподдержкой. На данный момент, если не хочешь заморачиваться с сборкой `PyQt5` из исходников, посмотри на 25 градусов правее и твой взор упадет на `PySide`, который, как мне говорили, ставится в разы проще (даже `make` писать в терминале не придется =)). По поводу твоего вопроса о `Qt Designer`'е, этот "товарисч" ставится в комплекте с `Qt` (его `C++`'ой ипостасью). Алгоритм действий далее такой:

```
1) Открываешь Дизайнер и прототипируешь в нем интерфейс;
2) Сохраняешь в `.ui` файл;
3) Используешь утилиту `pyuic5` (идет в комплекте)
4) ???
5) profit.run()
```

Потом согласно гайдам всех расцветок и мастей (просто набери в гугле `PyQt5` и на тебя посыпятся годные и не очень гайды) используешь полученный на выходе файл в твоем приложении.

Ах, и да, по поводу `IDE` - для `Python` - только  и только `PyCharm`, он, кажется, не мог в синтаксис `QML`, но до `QML` тебе еще далеко, как я понял, поэтому юзай смело.

Comment: По опыту Qt вообще не понравился. Ставил его для C++ в итоге, во время запуска прогрыммы не в среде (запуск release), показывал только ошибки и не мог найти.lib файлы..

Answer (score 0):

Я при выборе IDE остановился Wing Personal и geany.
Может быть они и Вам понравятся. Главное не отчаивайтесь и двигайтесь вперед.
И еще, можно вообще никаких IDE не использовать и в этом есть своеобразный кайф. Уж поверьте старику.
Успехов!